# I have a scenario where either the application will run in background without UI or foreground with UI. I decide on the bases of argument it received

Tags: c#, background, window

I have a scenario where either the application will run in the background without UI or foreground with UI. I decide on the bases of argument it received in Program.cs
But In background mode, the application calls`mergeProcess.Start();` and wait to complete the processing and then it Calls Application.Run(). But I want to call `mergeProcess.Start()` and then call `Application.Run()` or calling `mergeProcess.Start()` in Application Thread like `Application.Run(mergeProcess.Start())`
Any idea how should I do it?
The main Method is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ///*-------checking args length-----*/      
    if (args.Length>0) //It means the Application should run without UI
    {
            MergeProcess mergeProcess = null;             
            if(mergeProcess!=null)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Starting PPTViewFiles in Simple_Mode");
                mergeProcess.Start();
                Application.Run();
            }                       
    }
    else //It means the Application should run with UI
    {
        Application.Run(new PPTViewFileGUI());
    }               
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. You show a piece of code what seems to be doing what you write. So what is your problem?

Comment: My problem is when mergeProcess.Start() completes its execution and there is a logic it Start Method to close application itself which is called .
But when it reacher to Application.Run() method it keep the application running